# I want to create app in Docusign which can withstand for long time by using JWT token method

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I am creating app in my docusign developer account, using JWT token to get access token But while creating jwt , i am facing issue to fill "sub" value. Plesae suggest me from where i can get this value .
Also, tell me about time period i can use jwt to get access token

"sub" value clarification and time period

```
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "user_not_found"
```

Comment: ***Welcome! Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!!***

Answer (score 0):

`sub` is the user id of the DocuSign user you want your application to impersonate (via the JWT grant).

You can find a person's user id by looking them up on the DocuSign web app: click `Settings` in the top navigation, then click `Users` in the Administration (Settings) web app

### Re duration of access tokens

Access tokens returned by the OAuth JWT flow last an hour. Cache them (record its create time). When you need one (to make an API call), use the one in your cache if it is 50 minutes old or younger.

If you need a new one, use the JWT flow, add it to your cache and use it for your API call.